# Passing a collection byval

Tags: vb6

I am looking for since few hours on the Internet but I don't find if it is possible to pass to a function a collection byval ?

I put an example below and as you can see, the function ObjPtr return the same long pointer thus collTemp and myCollection are the same despite ByVal argument.

Is anyone have an idea ?

My code :

```
private sub function1

  dim myCollection as new collection

  call myFunction(mycollection)

  'For example, ObjPtr(myCollection) = 123456
end sub

'in another class
private sub myFunction(ByVal collTemp as Collection)

   'some code
   'ObjPtr(collTemp) = 123456

end sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing the collection ByVal, not passing ByVal the value stored inside the collection.

Why not pass by reference, clone the values inside your method, and use the cloned values?

[check here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5ce915e2-bbb8-48a6-9e04-53edccd39110/is-there-a-problem-with-passing-a-collections-parameter-byval-in-vba)

> When looking at the Collection as an object passed ByVal, the only thing actually being cloned is the reference to the collection...

Comment: yes i can clone the collection, but I thought that the passage of the ByVal collection was doing a copy of the collection and all the elements within.

Comment: A collection is always passed by ref, therefore if you change it inside a method it will be reflected outside, even more, if you are iterating in a collection you should not change it, it would rise an exception.
you can change the members of the collected instances though.

Comment: every Object is always passed by reference. The ByRef and ByVal modifers indicate how the reference is passed to the called procedure

Answer (score 2):

Objects are not passed "by reference" or even passed at all.  What you are passing are *object references* and these can be passed ByVal or ByRef.

If you pass one ByRef the procedure can modify what object the caller's reference actually references.

If you wish to return a new Collection instance then create one and return a reference to it.

Answer (score -1):

I believe `ByVal` and `ByRef` don't work with `Call` inside the same component. Try the same but omit the `Call`

Comment: `Call` is simply a redundant, deprecated keyword used for subroutine calls that offers a different syntax.  There is no difference in semantics.

Comment: Are you sure about that? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx

Comment: Bob77 is correct - it has been optional since at least VB1. The only good thing about it is that it implicitly resolves the ambiguities inherent in the VB procedure call syntax. VB.NET's syntax, whilst incompatible, removed the ambiguity without using the CALL keyword.

Comment: The real issue is that people who don't know the correct syntax for a subroutine call often add extraneous parens and either get a syntax error or direct the compiler to evaluate an inline expression and pass its value.  Using `Call` sort of dumbs things down but it's one heck of a *visual thunk* to stumble over when reading code.

Comment: I'm using `Call` with API functions only. By habit, not that it helps a lot.

Comment: Guess I don't remember VB6 as well as I thought I did!